# Updating referenced variables in functions in python

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to change the order of the matrix X through class P, which is already passed to a function in the base class B. The change in order does not reflect in the base class B. Is there a way to achieve this? Please see the following MWE:

```
#p.py
import numpy as np
import b

class P(b.B):

    def __init__(self, opts):
        self.opts = opts

    def func1(self, X):

        print('func1:',X)

    def func2(self):

        randomize = np.arange(len(self.myX))
        np.random.shuffle(randomize)
        self.myX = self.myX[randomize]

        print('func2',self.myX)

    def func3(self, X):
        """
        X is a 2d matrix 
        """
        self.myX = X
        #call the function from the base class 
        b.B.func3(self, self.myX)  

#b.py
class B:
    """
    base class.

    """
    def __init__(self, opts):
        self.opts = opts


    def func3(self, X):

        for n in range(2):
            for i in range(X.shape[0]):
                self.func1(X[i])
            self.func2()
```

from the console:

```
p1 = p.P({})
X=np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6], [5,6,7], [6,7,8]])
p1.func3(X)
```

Current Output:

```
func1: [1 2 3]
func1: [2 3 4]
func1: [3 4 5]
func1: [4 5 6]
func1: [5 6 7]
func1: [6 7 8]
func2 [[6 7 8]
 [3 4 5]
 [2 3 4]
 [5 6 7]
 [4 5 6]
 [1 2 3]]
func1: [1 2 3]
func1: [2 3 4]
func1: [3 4 5]
func1: [4 5 6]
func1: [5 6 7]
func1: [6 7 8]
```

Expected Output:

```
func1: [1 2 3]
func1: [2 3 4]
func1: [3 4 5]
func1: [4 5 6]
func1: [5 6 7]
func1: [6 7 8]
func2 [[6 7 8]
 [3 4 5]
 [2 3 4]
 [5 6 7]
 [4 5 6]
 [1 2 3]]
func1: [6 7 8]
func1: [3 4 5]
func1: [2 3 4]
func1: [5 6 7]
func1: [4 5 6]
func1: [1 2 3]
```

So basically, when the control returns from p.func2 to func3 in B, X should be the same as self.myX. I believe this should happen because self.myX is by default passed  by reference to b.func3.

Comment: Can you clarify which behaviour you get and which you expect? Running your code unmodified correctly calls the methods of ``P`` for me.

Comment: Did you mean you expected `B.func3()` to call upon `B.func1()` and `B.func2()` instead of `P.func1()` and `P.func2()`? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: You are actually overwriting all the methods from the base class `B` so I'm not sure the point of you using `b.B` as a base class.  You don't even need that base class since you are directly referencing `b.B.func3` in your `p.P.func3` anyways.  If you mean to keep the methods of `b.B` you would need to name the functions differently.  "Changes not reflecting in base class `B`" is also confusing because you really only created a `P` instance with the base `B`.  There's no instance of `B` for you to observe any reflection - everything happens under `P()`.

Comment: @Idlehands this is a minimum working version of a big code. I just want to get this problem fixed so did not feel necessary to include other details of the functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
#class p.P
    def func2(self):

        randomize = np.arange(len(self.myX))
        np.random.shuffle(randomize)
        self.myX = self.myX[randomize]  # <-- this line

        print('func2',self.myX)
```

You effectively reassigned `self.myX` to a *new* randomized np array, changing the object reference away from `X` to this new randomized array.

If you added a `print(id(self.myX))` between this line, you'll notice the initial reference points back to `X`, but once you reassigned it, the `id` is not longer the same.

You should do this instead to maintain the reference:

```
np.random.shuffle(self.myX)
```

If you actually wanted to shuffle the inner array as well:

```
for arr in self.myX:
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
np.random.shuffle(self.myX)
```

This will also maintain the reference.

Edit: If you wish to keep a reference of the randomized order while still maintaining the object, it's a bit trickier but doable:

```
# use make randomize an instance attribute so you can refer to it even after the function ended
self.shuffle_order = np.arange(len(self.myX))
np.random.shuffle(self.shuffle_order)

# loop through each inner array and reassign based on a copy of the shuffled matrix
for i, arr in enumerate(self.myX[self.shuffle_order]):
    self.myX[i] = arr
```

This changes the inner array but maintain the overall object reference between `self.myX` and `X`.

Afterwards you can retrieve the order via `p1.shuffle_order`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This really works! However, I want to save the order in which they are randomized to shuffle other corresponding arrays. Is that possible?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a take on referencing the shuffled order afterwards.